# Create an executable process without using shell on Python 2.5 and below

Tags: python, process, fork, subprocess, popen

Just what the title says:

1. The `subprocess` module cannot be used as this should work on 2.4 and 2.5
2. Shell process should not be spawned to pass arguments.

To explain (2), consider the following code:

```
>>> x=os.system('foo arg')
sh: foo: not found
>>> x=os.popen('foo arg')
sh: foo: not found
>>>
```

As you can see `os.system` and `os.popen` runs the given command ("foo") via a system shell ("sh"). I don't want this to happen (otherwise, ugly 'not found' messages are printed to program stderr without my control).

Finally, I should be able to pass arguments to this program ('arg' in the above example).

How would one go about doing this in Python 2.5 and 2.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use the subprocess module which is available in Python 2.4

```
Popen("/home/user/foo" + " arg")

>>> Popen("foo arg", shell=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1092, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

You will need to include the full path since you aren't using the shell.

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system

Alternatively you can also pass subprocess.PIPE to the stderr and stdout to suppress the messages. See the link above for more details.

Comment: Err, subprocess is available from 2.4? I deluded myself thinking that it is available from 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

As previously described, you can (and should) use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

By default, `shell` parameter is `False`. This is good, and quite safe. Also, you don't need to pass the full path, just pass the executable name and the arguments as a sequence (tuple or list).

```
import subprocess

# This works fine
p = subprocess.Popen(["echo","2"])

# These will raise OSError exception:
p = subprocess.Popen("echo 2")
p = subprocess.Popen(["echo 2"])
p = subprocess.Popen(["echa", "2"])
```

You can also use these two convenience functions already defined in subprocess module:

```
# Their arguments are the same as the Popen constructor
retcode = subprocess.call(["echo", "2"])
subprocess.check_call(["echo", "2"])
```

Remember you can redirect `stdout` and/or `stderr` to `PIPE`, and thus it won't be printed to the screen (but the output is still available for reading by your python program). By default, `stdout` and `stderr` are both `None`, which means *no redirection*, which means they will use the same stdout/stderr as your python program.

Also, you can use `shell=True` and redirect the `stdout`.`stderr` to a PIPE, and thus no message will be printed:

```
# This will work fine, but no output will be printed
p = subprocess.Popen("echo 2", shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
# This will NOT raise an exception, and the shell error message is redirected to PIPE
p = subprocess.Popen("echa 2", shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```